# how to withColumn an item of a vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some DataFrame which is the predictions from a transform of a pipeline model that represents a logistic regression model. It produces a "probability" column that is a vector, presumably representing the regression line relative to the predictable values (0 and 1). How do I get to the values? My naive approach:

```
predictionDF.select("probability").show()
predictionDF.select("probability").printSchema()
prediction.withColumn("certainty_no_brudd",
                      col("probability").cast("vector")(0))
```

gives me the following output:

```
+--------------------+
|         probability|
+--------------------+
|[0.79704719956042...|
|[0.96065621060123...|
|[0.94869126147921...|
|[0.98881973295162...|
|[0.94738842407184...|
|[0.99517040850391...|
|[0.67513098659304...|
|[0.98185993174719...|
|[0.88716858689769...|
|[0.94886839225328...|
|[0.87093946910993...|
|[0.93752063096904...|
|[0.99093365566705...|
|[0.97163117781123...|
|[0.88384736556118...|
|[0.89095359364458...|
|[0.94304454190511...|
|[0.96116865958545...|
|[0.91555675983743...|
|[0.96092603080292...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows

root
 |-- probability: vector (nullable = true)

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
DataType vector() is not supported.(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
vector
^^^


at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder$$anonfun$visitPrimitiveDataType$1.apply(AstBuilder.scala:1440)
...
```

Comment: @mtoto if I wanted to change the threshold, I could use ProbabilisticClassifier.setThresholds, but thats not what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: What do you mean by `"how do I get to the values"`, please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


val getItem = udf((v: Vector, i: Int) => v(i))

prediction.withColumn("certainty_no_brudd", getItem($"probability", lit(0)))
```

Comment: udf is an abbreviation for User Defined Function?

Comment: @qonf Yes, it's User Definied Function